# CSS image resize issue

Tags: html, css, image

I have a problem when resizing images I have set up in admin panel.

```
.users-list>li img {
    border-radius: 50%;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

When maximized, the images are looking great:

[image]

If I however resize browser, they all shrink together:

[image]

And then I tried by deleting the `height: 100px` property which seems to do the trick, but one image is for some reason off:

[image]

Comment: using `max-height:100px;` and `max-width:100px;` instead of `height:100px;` and `max-width:100%;` ?

Comment: width:100%;height:auto;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you do not want your images to stretch out, you should pin down one dimension and allow the other dimension as `auto`. (this preserves the aspect ratio of the image)

See the example below where `width` is kept constant while `height` auto-adjusts:

```css
img {
  display: block;
}
.correct,
.incorrect {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: inline-block;
}
.incorrect img {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
.correct img {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 200px;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div>This one stretches out:</div>
<div class="incorrect">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x50" />
</div>

<div>This will preserve aspect ratio and look right:</div>
<div class="correct">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x50" />
</div>
```

See the example below where `height` is kept constant while `width` auto-adjusts:

```css
img {
  display: block;
}
.correct,
.incorrect {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: inline-block;
}
.incorrect img {
  max-height: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
.correct img {
  max-height: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<div>This one stretches out:</div>
<div class="incorrect">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/150x50" />
</div>

<div>This will preserve aspect ratio and look right:</div>
<div class="correct">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/150x50" />
</div>
```

Comment: This makes a lot of sense...then my formatting is as good as it gets. Back-end needs to retrieve same dimension images in order to do what I want

Answer (score 0):

Just remove

```
height: 100px;
```

i.e

```
.users-list>li img {
    border-radius: 50%;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    width: 100px;
}
```

Comment: That gives me the 3rd picture result

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `height` attribute in `<img>` tag.

Like this
`<img src="/path/to/image" height="40">` without any CSS