# full width image container

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to have full width responsive image in a container in bootstrap. The size of the image I am using is 800 by 667. When I use the below code, what happens is image is not fully scaled in large screens. can someone help me please?

```
 <div class="myDiv">
        <img class="myImage" src="...." >
    </div>
```

Css:

```
.myDiv {
    padding: 0;
}
.myImage {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 500px;

}
```

Comment: Do you want the image to remain at 500px height no matter the width of the screen?

Comment: Please create  jsfiddle.

Comment: no, but even If I set it auto, the image is not scaled full width. I wondering why?

Comment: @Bing if want to maintain the `aspect ratio` of the image i.e., you don't want it to stretch it out- you should pin down one dimension and set the other `auto` (see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39289576/css-image-resize-issue/39289947#39289947) for more explanation)...

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ravrav/2hx7fv2f/
Here is my jsfiddle link. now the image is in full width but the image height is really long as it is in auto.

Comment: @Bing that is expected behaviour... hope you have read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39289576/css-image-resize-issue/39289947#39289947) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a fixed height. Try setting height: auto; to maintain the scale

Comment: I tried but still the image is not scaled full width.

Comment: This is something you should put in a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Remove "max" from max-width so it's just width:100%

Comment: Zedkay22, I removed max, and set height to auto, the image has full width now but the height is much more awkward.

Comment: You can specify the height without it being auto if you like. So just change height back to the pixels you wanted. Height:500px;

Comment: zedkay22, I changed it back to height:500px. It works good in large device.But it might end up looking long mobile devices. Is there any other way to mention the height so that it will look nice in smaller devices as well? Thanks

Comment: Implement a max height instead. So change height:500px; to max-height:500px;  let me know if that works for you !

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is remove the `max-width` and replace it with just `width`.

If you want to set it a specific height, use the `transform: scaleX(), scaleY()` property on the `image`.

```
.myImage {
    transform: scaleX(1.5); //scales the image 1.5 times for the X-axis
}
```

```css
.myDiv {
  padding: 0;
}
.myImage {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="myDiv">
  <img class="myImage" src="http://instantentity.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/Instant-Entity-CSS.jpg">
</div>
```