# Scaling img with window, max-width

Tags: css

I have a 64px that I would want to scale with browser window I have added max-width 100% but the image stays the same.

Html

```
<img src="../images/GitHub-Mark-64px.png">
```

CSS

```
img{
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39289576/css-image-resize-issue/39289947#39289947) might also help you..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your image is smaller than the containing DIV, your CSS rule won't make it any bigger. Try to use `width` instead of `max-width`:

```
img{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

Addition/Edit after Comments of OP:

You can use *any* percentage value in this rule, like 60% (or whatever you like), but using `width`, not `max-width` (which is only a maximum limit, but not an actual size definition).

But note: It won't really look good if the original image is smaller than displayed and is "blown up".

Comment: The only containing div is the wrapper so making it 100% would make the img cover the whole site. I would want the img to be half the size as the maximum and get smaller when resizing the window.

Comment: so what do you mean by "I would want to scale with browser window"?

Comment: Basically the smaller window the smaller img? Would that only work if the img is the size of the whole window?

Comment: Well, then just use a different percentage value, like 60% (or whatever you like), but using `width`, not `max-width`

Answer (score 1):

Try using `width` instead of `max-width` in your CSS, width attribute actually sets the width of the img. However, setting it to 100% would actually cover the entire space, so perhaps you should use a lesser percentage accordingly.

Comment: That was a mistake with copying I've fixed the question it still doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

Read: [CSS Image size, how to fill, not stretch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11757537/css-image-size-how-to-fill-not-stretch)

### If you want to use the image as a CSS background, there is an elegant solution. Simply use cover or contain in the background-size CSS3 property.

```
width: 100%;
height: 100%
background-size: cover;
```