# Adjusting an image

Tags: html, css, image, centering

I need to adjust my image to a nav bar, but i can't seem to resize or "move" the picture. What is wrong? (The image need to be in center, and be resized to fit the nav bar width)

```css
.forsidebillede {
width: 1000px;
height: 100px;
display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto
}
```

```html
<section class="forsidebillede">
<img src="https://a2ua.com/grey/grey-002.jpg" alt="smoothies"/>
</section>
```

Comment: Have you tried `display: inline-block;` on the image?

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39289576/css-image-resize-issue/39289947#39289947) might get you started...

Comment: It puts the image on the left side of the screen.

Comment: add `text-align: center` to `.forsidebillede`

Comment: text-align dosesn't do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no code here actually referencing the image.

The below would do this.

```css
.forsidebillede {
width: 1000px;
height: 100px;
display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto
}

.forsidebillede > img {
    width:100%;
    height:100%; /* Only if you want the height to be filled also */
    display:block; /* To remove any extra spacing */
}
```

```html
<section class="forsidebillede">
<img src="smoothie.jpg" alt="smoothies"/>
</section>
```

Comment: Excellent, no problem!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by resize to fit navbar.
But centering can be simple.

```css
.forsidebillede {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 100px;
  display: block;
  margin:0 auto;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<section class="forsidebillede">
<img src="http://www.jambajuice.com/~/media/www/images/products/product/smoothies/almond-milk-smoothies-promotion/Almond%20Milk%20smoothies%20category%20image.ashx" alt="smoothies"/>
</section>
```

I am completely guessing but are you truying to resize the image to fits its container? Like this?

```css
.forsidebillede {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 100px;
  display: block;
  margin:0 auto;
  text-align:center;
}
.forsidebillede img{
  height:100%; 
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<section class="forsidebillede">
<img src="http://www.jambajuice.com/~/media/www/images/products/product/smoothies/almond-milk-smoothies-promotion/Almond%20Milk%20smoothies%20category%20image.ashx" alt="smoothies"/>
</section>
```

Comment: It's not clear what end result you want. How do you want to resize?

Comment: I didn't refer to the "img", thats why i couldn't adjust size. But it's working now!

Comment: I did. But had to wait a few minutes to be allowed.

Comment: Good luck with your project. :)

Answer (score 0):

Hello just add this extra Css in your style

```
  .forsidebillede img{
   width:100%;
   height:100%;
   }
```