# Maintaining image aspect ratio for a fixed height

Tags: html, css, image, responsive-design

I have an image of height 600px. And I'm using it with an img tag, than a background image. Reason is because of responsiveness. I want the image to resize based on screen sizes. But i want my image to be of height 300px. Now if i set the `max-height:300px` and `width:100%`. The image looks stretched. Is there a way for the image to be proportioned as well as responsive based on screen sizes?

This is for a bootstrap carousel image.

Comment: Provide your code

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39289576/css-image-resize-issue/39289947#39289947) might get you started...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `width:auto;`, like the following example:

```css
img.non-stretched {
  max-height:300px;
  width:auto;
}
img.stretched {
  max-height:300px;
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<img class="non-stretched" src="http://placehold.it/600x600"/>
<img class="stretched" src="http://placehold.it/600x600"/>
```

The initial value of `width` is `auto` so you can remove the `width` property. But it's safer to set the `width` in your case because a used framework or other stylesheet can overwrite the rules with another value.

> You can find more information about the `width` property here: 
>   https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#the-width-property