# Image to Fit Containing Div

Tags: html, css

I have done this many times before but it doesn't seem to work now for whatever reason. I want the image to be the full the width of the container but it doesn't. Any ideas?

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lqffk1ak/

**Code:**

```css
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
div {
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://s11.postimg.org/dpgqru2pv/Police2_600x250.jpg" class="full-width">
</div>
```

Comment: Do you want it to stretch or zoom in?

Comment: You can set width to 100% but height will be changed accordingly

Comment: To fit width of container keeping aspect ratio

Comment: @pee2pee check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39289576/css-image-resize-issue/39289947#39289947)  - looks like it has the explanation there.

Comment: who downvoted this and why? this has a clear problem, enough code to replicate the issue in an MCVE. downvoting a****s are spoiling this site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add width:100% to img

```
img {
    width:100%
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your class, what you should add is some CSS on the `full-width` class to make the img width 100%.
This way, only the images set as "full-width" will be forced 100%. The other one will keep the `max-width` rule of 100%, but won't be resized if they are smaller.

```css
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
.full-width {
  width: 100%;
}
div {
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://s11.postimg.org/dpgqru2pv/Police2_600x250.jpg" class="full-width">
</div>
```

Comment: Why not ? This is the case currently. The image is 600px large, and if you put the snippet in full width, the image will be 100%. Note the `full-width` class on the image.

Comment: OP added a class `full-width` to his image. I added the `width:100%` on the full-width class to be more coherent with his code. So if the container is larger than 600px, the image still have the `width:100%` applied from the `full-width` class. Run the code snippet and expand it.

Answer (score 1):

Just make your **image width 100%**. Even you resize your container image will fit on it.

```
img{
width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check the updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Lqffk1ak/)

Change the css :

```
div {
    height: 100%;
}

img {
   width: 100%;
   min-height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this isn't directly an answer to your question but generally speaking, upscaled images look quite nasty. A way people get past this is to have the image centered and then add a blurred version behind it.

Like this:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.image {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 0px;
}
.background-image {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url('https://s11.postimg.org/dpgqru2pv/Police2_600x250.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  z-index: -1;
}
.blur {
  filter: blur(10px);
}
```

```html
<div class="image">
  <div class="background-image blur"></div>
  <img src="https://s11.postimg.org/dpgqru2pv/Police2_600x250.jpg" class="full-width">
</div>
```

I hope you find this helpful.

Comment: The theory is sound thank you. The images should be clipped to be the right size and aspect ratio but I'll have a think about how to use this.

Answer (score 0):

Because your Image is has `600px;` height, and the you have set `max-width:100%`. So `max-width` property will only work when the parent dive will be smaller then `600px;`.

To make image to the containing div, you have to give set image's property 100%; that is `.full-width {width: 100%;}`