# Responsive img with flexbox

Tags: html, image, css, flexbox

Hi and thanks to anyone replying to this post.

I have wrapped an `img` with an anchor tag and the `img` no longer shrinks as the page is resized. I know that flexbox only applies flex properties to child elements, so wrapping the `img` with an anchor would make it a grandchild. But even when applying flex to the anchor the image still fails to shrink.

```css
.rightContent {
    color: white;
    padding: 20px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
    justify-content: space-between;
    background: #375D81;
}

.leftContent {
    color: white;
    padding: 20px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    background: #183152;
}
```

```html
    <div class="rightContent">
        <h3>Date Added: 11/4/2016</h3>
        <p>dictum elit pretium. In sagittis euismod diam a pharetra. Nunc venenatis aliquet massa sed mollis. Nulla nec est metus. Aliquam in tortor </p>
        <a href="https://color.adobe.com/explore/most-popular/?time=all">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="" /></a>
    </div>

    <div class="leftContent">
        <h3>Date Added: 11/4/2016</h3>
        <p>dictum elit pretium. In sagittis euismod diam a pharetra. Nunc venenatis aliquet massa sed mollis. Nulla nec est metus. Aliquam in tortor</p>
        <a href="http://lorempixel.com/"></a><img class="right " src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="" />
    </div>
```

Comment: Try giving the anchor `min-width: 0`. http://stackoverflow.com/q/36247140/3597276

Comment: Didnt work im afraid. Thanks for the link though, was an interesting read.

Comment: could you please create a snippet with an example in order we could help?

Comment: Added a snippet :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image is not shrinking as the image is not constrained to the flex-item `a` - just use this:

```
a img{
  width: 100%;
}
```

and now the `img` will respect the dimensions of `a`. See [here for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39289576/css-image-resize-issue/39289947#39289947) on how we restrict the dimensions of images without affecting the intrinsic `aspect-ratio`.

```css
.rightContent {
    color: white;
    padding: 20px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
    justify-content: space-between;
    background: #375D81;
}

.leftContent {
    color: white;
    padding: 20px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    background: #183152;
}
a img{
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="rightContent">
        <h3>Date Added: 11/4/2016</h3>
        <p>dictum elit pretium. In sagittis euismod diam a pharetra. Nunc venenatis aliquet massa sed mollis. Nulla nec est metus. Aliquam in tortor </p>
        <a href="https://color.adobe.com/explore/most-popular/?time=all">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="" /></a>
    </div>

    <div class="leftContent">
        <h3>Date Added: 11/4/2016</h3>
        <p>dictum elit pretium. In sagittis euismod diam a pharetra. Nunc venenatis aliquet massa sed mollis. Nulla nec est metus. Aliquam in tortor</p>
        <a href="http://lorempixel.com/"><img class="right " src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="" /></a>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the second image inside the a tag(it's outside the a tag in your markup), ie

```
<a href="http://lorempixel.com/"><img class="right" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="" /></a>
```

and apply the following CSS.

```
.leftContent a img,
.rightContent a img{
    max-width:100%;
}
```